# module not found OpenJDK 12 Maven Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-module

**Environment**: OpenJDK 12, Maven 3.6.1, Eclipse 4.12, Modules are 2 separate projects in the same workspace.

**Context**: I'm trying to compile 2 simple modules.

**Issue**: message-> module not found when compiling 2nd module

---

1st Module:

---

```
public class Car{
    //Strings attributes
    public Car(args){
      //set args
    }
    //getter & setters
}
module ModuleCars {
    exports com.org.car; //the class is inside this package
}
```

POM:

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>cars</groupId>
  <artifactId>ModuleCars</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>12</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
```

Run Maven **clean compile**: ok

---

2nd module:

---

```
public class CarFactory  {

       private static CarFactory instance;
        private CarFactory() {          
        }
        public static synchronized CarFactory getInstance() {
            if(instance == null) {
                instance = new CarFactory();
            }
            return instance;
        }
        public Car createCar() {
            return new Car("5","Red","01/01/2019");
        }
}

module ModuleFactory {
    requires transitive ModuleCar;
    exports com.org.factory; //the class is inside this package
}
```

Pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>factory</groupId>
  <artifactId>ModuleFactory</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>12</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
```

**Project Properties:** -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> Module Path-> Add ModuleCars

**Run Maven:** clean compile: **module not found: ModuleCars**

**Update 1:**
The conection between the modules is made with Eclipse (with the Module path), is the only way I have found.

Comment: In Maven, how does the second module know about the first module? Do you have a parent POM, or does the second module fetch the first module from a Maven repository to which the first module has been published?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in your second module the first module as dependency:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>cars</groupId>
     <artifactId>ModuleCars</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And you have to install your first Module using clean install.